# How to make a flex container auto-grow as its flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a CSS grid whose elements are flex containers. I'm trying to make the grid's columns auto-size based on the sizing rules of the *flex items* within the flex containers.

Below is an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve. Is it possible to obtain the desired behavior?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-feather-2605q4?file=/index.html)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  background: rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Desired behavior</b>: the flex item auto-grows up to its maximum width, which defines the size of the grid column</p>

<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 216px 1fr;">
  <div class="cell"><div class="item"></div></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>

<p><b>Actual result</b>: the flex item doesn't auto-grow because the `flex` rule can't make its flex container grow</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"><div class="item"></div></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-width` to the flex item that matches the `max-width`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  background: rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"><div class="item"></div></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the min-width of the flex container to the same value as the max-width property of the flex item.

```css
.cell{
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  background: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  min-width: 0; /* will allow cell container to shrink */
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  /* set min-width to same value as max-width */
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Desired behavior</b>: the flex item auto-grows up to its maximum width, which defines the size of the grid column</p>

<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 216px 1fr;">
  <div class="cell"><div class="item"></div></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>

<p><b>Actual result</b>: the flex item doesn't auto-grow because the `flex` rule can't make its flex container grow</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"><div class="item"></div></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

```
This should work
```